# How to add arrayList<model> items to an listView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I want to add every element of an arrayList to a listView ,Here I am passing an arrayList to the adapter which contains package name and size ,
How to iterate and display all the items in the listView.

```
 public class CCacheAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CCacheInfo>
{
 private ArrayList<CCacheInfo> arrayList;
 private Context mContext;
 public CCacheAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CCacheInfo> cacheInfos)
{
    super(context,0, cacheInfos);
    mContext=context;
    arrayList=cacheInfos;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    CCacheInfo cCacheInfo = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder oViewHolder;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cache_items, parent, false);
        oViewHolder =new ViewHolder();
        oViewHolder.mPackageName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.package_name);
        oViewHolder.mPackageSize = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.package_size);
        oViewHolder.mPackageIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);
        oViewHolder.mCheckbox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        convertView.setTag(oViewHolder);
    }else
    {
        oViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
        oViewHolder.mPackageName.setText(cCacheInfo.m_szAppName);
        oViewHolder.mPackageSize.setText(CCleanTool.formatShortFileSize(mContext, cCacheInfo.m_nSize));
    return convertView;
}
private class ViewHolder
{
    TextView mPackageName;
    TextView mPackageSize;
    CheckBox mCheckbox;
    ImageView mPackageIcon;
 }
  }
```

Comment: you are not gonna do it by yourself, adapter will do it. Just set adapter to ListView

Answer (score 0):

Just set the adapter to ListView, like the following

```
ArrayList<CCacheInfo> cacheInfos = ... // you get your data from somewhere
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
CCacheAdapter adapter = new CCacheAdapter(this, cacheInfos);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```